# Apache Redirect help

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am a newbie in this department.I have following folder structure
root
root\html
root\html\html

the root\html\html has our old website with a bunch of pages in .html form. The \html has our new website with .htm extension

I want to have a .htaccess in the root/html/html which basically any call to a file.html to  root/html/file.htm

so www.example.com/html/file.html will become www.example.com/file.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this:

```
RewriteRule ^/html/(.*)\.html$ /$1.htm [R]
```

should do what you want.

If you don't want to redirect (if you don't want the address in the browser's address bar to change) just take the [R] out.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^/html/(.*).html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.htm [R=301,L]